# Back button reopens the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-event

There are a few times when the user presses the back button on my app, and unfortunately he doesn't get out; the activity slides, but behind it there is exactly the same one...How is that possible? How could I avoid it? should I implementate something for the onBackPressed() method?
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I didn't provide any implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do implement onBackPressed. This sounds like multiple instances of the activity are being created/started, which is expected default behaviour when calling .startActivity() Check out the docs [Tasks and Back Stack.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
You could use singleTop as the launchmode or set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`
on the intent that launches the activity.

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
detailsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` your activity deceleration in the `Manifest` .